# Algorithm Analysis

Tags: big-o

So I understand a little bit of algorithm analysis, but I'm at a complete loss to understand how to do this one. Can someone please explain this to me? Would this be O(logn)?

```
for (int i=1; i < n; i*=2)
for (int j=0; j < i; j++)
// do simple operation
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the big O of the nested loops, you need to do steps like the following example.

For example, let:

```
n = 10
```

now the outer loop executes 3 time that is:

```
i=2,4 and 8
```

and inner loops executes 3 time for each iteration like

```
i=2 it iterates 2 times
i=4 it iterates 4 times
i=8 it iterates 8 times
```

so the total number of iterations are less the 2*n which makes it O(2n) we can neglect the constant factor so its big O is

```
O(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's actually `O(n)`

You can figure this out as follows:

- The number of operations is the sum of the series 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, ...... which stops just before `n`.
- The sum of this geometric series is approximately in the range from `n` to `2n`.
- Hence the whole algorithm is `O(n)` since you can ignore the constant factor.

Comment: but when we consider the inner for loop, wouldn't that result to O(n^2)? Since 1 + 2 + ... + n is O(n^2)

Comment: You can try and sum each `i` of each loop. E. g. 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 etc... the sum will always be between 1/2 n and 2 n. If n = 4 then the sum of all i = 2. If n = 129 then the sum of all i = 254.

Comment: The sum isn't `O(n^2)` - you need to do the sum of a geometric progression. It would be `O(n^2)` if it was an arithmetic progression, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

I will first calculate **little-o** for you to understand the whole process and then we will get **big-O** from it.

Let's take it into parts:

```
for (int i=2; i < n; i*=2)
```

First we have 1 bound from `i=2`

If `i*=2` then **i ={2,4,8,16,32,64...}** so **i** increments following **2^x** then:

We are looking for **i > n** to be true so it is **2^x > n** whats needs to be true, doing a little of maths:

**log2(2^x) = log2(n)**

**x=log2(n)** //Here we figured out that `i` will need **log2(n)** loops to satisfy conditional statement.

Since in the `for` we have comparisons and bounds it will be **2log2(n)+1** operations for this `for`.

**Notice:** since this is a nested chain each operation in the following `for` will be multiplied **2log2(n)+1** times

```
for (int j=0; j < i; j++)
```

`j=0` 1 bound

`j++` **j={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8....}** so **j=n** then it goes **2n+1** for this `for`

Finally we have that **little o** is equal to:

**(2n+1)*(2log2(n)+1)**

**4nlog2(n) + 2n + 2log2(n) + 1**

**log2(n)(4n+2) +2n +1**

It turns out that **o(log2(n)(4n+2) +2n +1)**, and in order to get **big O** we can reduce this expression neglecting some factors, then:

**O(log2(n)n)**

Hope it is clear enough to understand.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you can proceed like the following:

[image]